# While loop warns of always true since value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int'

Tags: c#, .net, while-loop, streamreader

I'm new to C#, working through some examples in the C# Head First book and trying to apply what I've learned in a practical manner. I'm trying to read in a text file with the following code:

```
private StreamReader upload;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Recon 5\Desktop\ToDo.txt"))
    {
        upload = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Recon 5\Desktop\ToDo.txt");
        while (upload.Peek() != null)
        {
            currentTasks.Items.Add(upload.ReadLine());
        }
        upload.Close();
    }
}
```

The above code provides the intended result, i.e. adding items into a list box from a text file. What I don't understand is why the following expression:

```
upload.Peek() != null
```

is giving me the following compiler warning:

> *The result of the expression is always `true` since a value of type `int` is never equal to `null` of type `int`.*

I've tried looking in the Windows [library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx) for a response, but understanding the API is a task in its own right.

I guess what I'm looking for is helpful pointers to either guide my search or resources to assist me in discovering the answer myself. I'm sure there might be a better way to write this task but given where I'm at with my understanding of the language I feel it important to use and understand the tools I have learned thus far, in this case the `while` loop.

Comment: I think you should first learn the difference between value and reference types. Also - IntelliSense `Peek()` documentation should tell you exactly what values can it return, so you could know what to expect.

Comment: @Tarec, I appreciate the direction. Also playing around more with the IntelliSense your right it does indicate a return type of int, again thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while (upload.Peek() != null)
```

...looks suspicious since [`StreamReader.Peek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek.aspx) can't return `null`. I suspect the correct line would be;

```
while (upload.Peek() != -1)
```

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Int32
>   An integer representing the next character to be read, or -1 if there are no characters to be read or if the stream does not support seeking.

Comment: Gotcha, and actually now that you pointed that out I dug into reader.peek and found that the int error is coming from this, it returns an integer value which then determines if there is anything else in the file. So I'm assuming if there is additional characters it would return 0 and if not then -1 which stops the loop?

Comment: @TargetofGravity It returns the integer value of the next character, or -1 if there is no next character in the stream, so if you want to read the entire stream, you just loop until it returns -1.